# Java/Android: I don't understand why this is slower than expected

Tags: java, android

I have this method:

```
@DebugLog
private synchronized int insertInOrderedFromBottom(ItemWithTime itemWithTime, ArrayList<ItemWithTime> array) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (itemWithTime == null || itemWithTime.getDateTime() == null) return -1;
    if (array == null) return -1;
    int arraySize = array.size();
    for (int i = arraySize - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (itemWithTime.getDateTime().isBefore(array.get(i).getDateTime())) {
            i++;
            array.add(i, itemWithTime);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d(TAG,"insertInOrderedFromBottom inside took "+(end-start));
            return i;
        }
    }
    array.add(itemWithTime);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.d(TAG,"insertInOrderedFromBottom inside took "+(end-start));
    return array.size();
}
```

Now, you see the log statements I use to measure the time it takes this method to complete:

- the logs say that the method to complete takes approx **0 mills**.

I call the method like this:

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
insertInOrderedFromBottom(datum, items);
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.d(TAG, "insertInOrderedFromBottom invoication took " + (end - start) + " ms");
```

- Here the log says it takes **10-15 mills**.

What is happening? What am I missing here?

EDIT

I have tried without synchronized and no difference.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. You first write 'They say that the method to complete takes approx 0 mills' (Who says that ?). Later your own log shows that it takes between 10-15 milliseconds. What is exactly your problem now ?

Comment: the logs say that: `Log.d(TAG, "insertInOrderedFromBottom, loop took " + (end - start) + " ms");`

Comment: Please read my questions and answer them. What about the first sentence of about 0 millis ? Who says that ? And what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: Ach I see, you changed the post. So your question is why the inner loop is fast and the full loop slow ?

Comment: the loop (according to the logs) takes 0ms. The overall method from start to finish takes 0 ms (according to the logs), but the logs before and after the **method invocation** show a difference of 15 ms

Comment: I think it would help if you share your log output for one run through this code

Comment: yep sharing the log output would be good, because only 1 start time is taken yet multiple end points are measured. So I guess the inner loop will print multiple log entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The android log function is fairly slow. So if you have a log inside the inner loop that prints a time difference then that in itself will take a number of milliseconds. The last output timing thus reflects the time necessary to perform the Log.d in the inner loop

Comment: Thanks Werner indeed it were the logs themselves that were slowing things down

Comment: Same with System.out.println statements. It is often surprising how much time is spent on I/O.